# Show view while website loads

Tags: android, url, stream

I have an application that uses a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) that loads a url like `facebook.com/exampleuser`.
It takes a few seconds to load this url. Is there any way to show a temporary View to create something similar to a splash screen at the start of the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can show a progress spinner (or anything else you may want) by doing the following. Bare in mind that this code works with Fragments so you may need to alter it slightly (I.E. remove `getActivity()`).

```
//declare the WebView
WebView webView;

//then in OnCreate()

final WebView webView = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                if(progress == 100) {               
                    try
                    {
                        //the layout contains a progress bar
                        View progress_bar =(View) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

                        if(progress_bar != null)
                            progress_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {}
                }
            }
        });
```